# Diff tool (for comparing minified files) which can ignore small changes (lines with one or two characters changed)

Tags: diff, beyondcompare

I sometimes want to diff the output of JS builds. The files are minified, so I first prettify them. The problem though is that sometimes small changes in the input yield *hundreds* of trivial changes in the output file, due to minification process assigning different variable names all over the output file.

I would like a diff tool that can ignore those small changes (that are typically 1 or 2 character diffs) and only show bigger diffs.

Is there a tool like that, or can Beyond Compare be configured like that?

A typical diff I'd like to ignore looks like this:

[image: diff with one character per line]

Comment: Can you post the two texts? That makes it easier to make an example.

Comment: Just as a remark - if you don't know it already: "so I first prettify them" - this can be done by beyondcompare itself. Examples are ["HTML Tidy and XML Tidy"](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_morerules) or https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformatsv4

Answer (score 1):

You can use replacements for this.

Go to Session->Session Settings->Replacements:

[image]

After this the difference is unimportant:
[image]

You may also define a replacement easier via the context menu (right mouse click)

### [image]

The official support page contains a possibility with file formats: https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the example I posted is just one of _hundreds_ of differences. It's just a small screenshot to illustrate, but defining replacements does not scale in general in my case (my file is 500kB and it has a diff like that every few lines).

Comment: Difficult to give a specific answer, without knowing which difference occur. Maybe a regeular expression may be useful?

Comment: No, not really. The JS minifier does random renamings and there are dozens of them without any pattern. Basically what I think I want is "ignore diff if diff is 1 or 2 characters in a line" (I can't think about anything else that would fit my requirement)

Comment: I mean, it's not the minifier who "does" the diff. It's just the way the minifier works is that you do small change in input (add a few lines of code), and suddenly dozens variables in output get renamed in a non-obvious way.